# Ternary operator not working in Haml

Tags: haml

This question has been asked but the answers have not worked. The problem I am having is this hamlc code:

```
 .UI_feed_item.deletable.clearfix{ :class => @feed.fav_post ? 'favorited' : '', feed_id: "#{@feed.id}", id: "feed_item_#{@feed.id}" }
   *a lot more haml that doesn't have to do with this question*
```

the indentation is correct - it shows up weird on here
I want an extra class added to say favorited if feed.fav_post is true. for some reason it added a class 'true' or 'false' instead. I have also tried this:

```
 .UI_feed_item.deletable.clearfix{ :class => (@feed.fav_post ? 'favorited' : ''), feed_id: "#{@feed.id}", id: "feed_item_#{@feed.id}" }
```

same result
I cannot do an if/else thing because there is no end in haml and I would have to rewrite a hundred lines of indented code. please help! none of the other solutions on the web have worked

Comment: Have you tried creating/setting a variable using the same ternary statement on a different line? Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/ethagnawl/5811717)?

Answer (score 0):

Your second shot should work fine. The first variant returns true/false because the hash rocket wins over the ternary operator in terms of precedence - but shouldn't it break on syntax error after that?

You can do if-else in haml.

```
- if true
  some stuff here
- else
  some other stuff here
```

Indentation is used instead of `end`.

Answer (score 0):

HAMLC doesn't support the ?/: ternary operators, but you can still achieve what you want using inline if/then/else. Try this:

```
.UI_feed_item.deletable.clearfix{ :class => "#{ if @feed.fav_post then 'favorited' else '' }", feed_id: "#{@feed.id}", id: "feed_item_#{@feed.id}" }
```